# Where to find gtk.lib file?

Tags: c++, gtk3

I have recently installed GTK+3.0 using Msys2 following the instructions on the gtk website. Everything seems in order, except I cannot find the required lib files. Where can they be found?

Comment: MinGW doesn't normally use `.lib`, you should be looking for `.a`. Did you try linking against those libraries, maybe GCC will find them out of the box? (That should be the case if you installed GTK from MSYS2's package manager.)

Comment: I did notice those files. I'm trying to compile my program using Visual Studio. Do I need to compile using MinGW instead?

Comment: MSYS2 and its packages are intended to be used with MinGW. So, either use MinGW, or find GTK for MSVC somewhere else.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the help.